# How do I calculate noise level of an audio file with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

Related questions on this site that unfortunately don't match my use case:

- [Compare two audio files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257925/compare-two-audio-files)
- [How to use sox or ffmpeg to detect silence intervals in a long audio file and replace them by zeros (aka suppress background noise)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192894/how-to-use-sox-or-ffmpeg-to-detect-silence-intervals-in-a-long-audio-file-and-re)

The DSP Stack Exchange site has nothing of value to offer:

- [Measuring how non-noisy a sound signal is](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/measuring-how-non-noisy-a-sound-signal-is) has meaningless answers.

**Problem**:

I download files from the Internet (YouTube, Vimeo, etc.), or transcode stuff from my FM radio. I would like to be able to calculate (from the command line) the following:

- (ideally) a pair of numbers: average Signal-to-Noise-Ratio (SNR) and its variance for the recording as a whole
- (not so ideally) a sequence of SNR values for e.g. each time slice of the recording (a second, a tenth etc.)
- (would work at a pinch) a spectrogram for each time slice of the recording

...using only GNU/FOSS command line tools - FFmpeg and anything I can get in source tarball form.

P.S. Can I do it with **`sox`**?

Comment: Turns out the question is quite involved, and `sox` offers no definite solution (but allows one to get the spectrogram from the command line). [ITU-R BS.468-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU-R_468_noise_weighting) standard filters should be used (unless one wants to go full U.S. of A with A-weighting).